# Unable to open Excel documents on SP 2010 website

Tags: 2010, excel, connection

As of today one specific user is having issues opening Excel documents from a Sharepoint 2010 site.
Whenever he tries to open one he gets the following error message.
The screenshot is in Dutch but the message reads:

```
Unable to connect to the server.
The file {filename} cannot be opened because a connection can't be made to the server.
                                  [Open again] [OK]
```

[image]

This is not a newly created website nor is it a new user. He has never had issues opening Excel documents in the past.
There's nothing wrong with his network connection.

Tried solutions:

- Reset Internet Explorer settings
- Repair Office installation
- Restart computer

But the issue remains.

Comment: Try to install English package to translete all sharepoint errors to English.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3411

Comment: @GrzegorzZ How should the installation of the English language pack help in solving this problem? Tom already posted the English translation of the screenshot in his question.

Comment: Because it will be easier to find out a problem. In my organization it was a problem with Internet Explorer, because on Firefox it works well.

Comment: Everything on the server is installed in English, it's just the user's Office that's configured in Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

> This problem occurs when the following conditions are true:
>   The server is configured for Basic authentication.
>   The connection between your computer and the web server does not use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).
>   By default, file operations that use Basic authentication over a non-SSL HTTP connection are disabled in Office 2010 and Office 2013 applications.
>
> When Basic authentication is disabled, one of the following events occurs:
>   The client application uses a different authentication method. This occurs if the server supports a different authentication method.
>   The request fails (for details about what happens when a request fails, see the list in the "Additional symptom details" section).
>
> If the workaround of using HTTPS instead of HTTP does not work, the resolution is to enable SSL encryption on the web server to allow for client access over HTTPS.
>
> To work around this problem, let Office 2013 and Office 2010 applications connect to a web server by using Basic authentication over a non-SSL connection.
>
> **Warning** When you enable Basic authentication without SSL, you are subject to a significant security risk.

Source: [Office file types fail to open from server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2123563?wa=wsignin1.0)